# Cypher: UNION 2 queries with different columns

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to combine 2 types of queries and return one result set using the COLLECT to create matching column names, but it's still giving me the 'All sub queries in an UNION must have the same column names' error. Is there any way to do this:

```
MATCH(i:Person{username:"wkolcz"})
MATCH(p:Person)-[]->(m:Meetup{status:"Accepted"})<-[]-(i),
(m)-[:MEETUP_AT]->(l:Location)
WHERE toInt(m.meet_date) >= 1446302204
RETURN COLLECT({name:p.first_name + " " + p.last_name,image_name: p.image_name, username:p.username,meeting_id:id(m) , meet_date:m.meet_date,
location_name:l.location_name, address:l.address, city:l.city, state:l.state, zip_code:l.zip_code,type:"person"})

UNION ALL 

MATCH(g:Group)-[:CREATED]->(gm:Meetup{status:"Active"})<-[:ATTENDING]-(i),
(gm)-[:MEETUP_AT]->(gl:Location)
WHERE toInt(gm.meet_date) >= 1446302204
RETURN COLLECT({name:g.group_name,image_name: g.image_name, username:g.group_slug,meeting_id:id(gm) , meet_date:gm.meet_date,
location_name:gl.location_name, address:gl.address, city:gl.city, state:gl.state, zip_code:gl.zip_code,type:"group"})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alias your column names to be the same thing.

```
RETURN COLLECT(...) AS data

UNION ALL

RETURN COLLECT(...) AS data
```